# Nginx rewrite servername and port

Tags: nginx

Can Nginx rewrite a full URL before it is given to the client?

I have a Django server connected to minio backend and serve by Nginx.
The server "www.abc.com" home page contains URLs with "www.minio.com:9000/static/my.css"
and I would like to rewrite that into "www.abc.com/static/my.css"
I would then be able to use proxy_pass to the original www.minio.com:9000/static/my.css

I have been trying to had Nginx rewrite clause in the server
without success at all.

```
upstream uwsgi {
    server 127.0.0.1:7999;  
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.abc.com;

    rewrite www.minio.com:9000 www.abc.com;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi; 
    }

    localtion /static {
        proxy_pass www.minio.com:9000/;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are trying to change the content of the page, `rewrite` is the wrong tool. You should try something like `sub_filter`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter).

Comment: Thanks @Richard Smith after I replaced the rewrite by sub_filter and sub_filter_once off, and the URLs are changed correctly but then the reverse proxy doesn't seem to compute

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the recommendation of sub_filter and other edits this is what seems to be working for me so far:

```
upstream uwsgi {
    server 127.0.0.1:7999;  
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.abc.com;

    sub_filter 'www.minio.com:9000' '';

    location /static/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass www.minio.com:9000;
    }

    location /media/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass www.minio.com:9000;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi; 
    }
}
```